# Question About Lipschitz Maps and Measure Zero

Tags: measure-theory

I'm having difficulty with a problem involving measure.

> Suppose $F : B^k \rightarrow B^n$ is a Lipschitz map from the unit ball in $\mathbb{R}^k$ to the unit ball in $\mathbb{R}^n$. If $k \lt n$, show that the image of $F$ has measure zero in $B^n$.

Starting from the fact that $F$ is a Lipschitz map, I figured out that for all $\epsilon \gt 0, \forall F(x), F(y) \in B^n$, if $F(x), F(y) \in B_\epsilon$ in $B^n$, then $x, y \in B_{\epsilon/C}$ in $B^k$ where $C$ is the Lipschitz constant.

From here I'm thinking that one can cover the $k$ unit ball with some $n$-balls and then transfer those $n$-balls to $B^n$ where they cover image $(F)$. Then reducing epsilon reduces the volume of the $n$-balls faster than their number increases so the volume goes to zero.

I would appreciate any help or tips. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Considering $B^k$ as a subset of $B^n$, you can extend $F$ to a map $G:B^n\to B^n$ such that $G(x_1,\ldots,x_n)=F(x_1,\ldots,x_k)$.  Note that $G$ is Lipschitz with the same Lipschitz constant as $F$.  The measure of $B^k$ in $B^n$ is $0$, so given $\varepsilon>0$ there is a sequence of balls $\{B(\mathbf{x}_i,r_i)\}_i$ in $B^n$ such that $B^k\subseteq \cup_i B(\mathbf{x}_i,r_i)$ and $\sum_i m(B(\mathbf{x}_i,r_i))<\varepsilon$.

Let $C>0$ be the Lipschitz constant of $F$, hence of $G$.  Then $G(B(\mathbf{x}_i,r_i))$ has diameter at most $2Cr_i$, and therefore it fits inside a ball of radius $2Cr_i$.  This implies that $m(G(B(\mathbf{x}_i,r_i))\leq (2C)^nm(B(\mathbf{x}_i,r_i)$.  Since 
$$F(B^k)=G(B^k)\subseteq G(\cup_iB(\mathbf{x}_i,r_i))=\cup_i G(B(\mathbf{x}_i,r_i)),$$
this implies that $m(F(B^k))<(2C)^n\varepsilon$. Since $C$ and $n$ are constants and $\varepsilon$ was arbitrary, this implies that $m(F(B^k))=0$.

---

Regarding your remarks, note that $d(F(x),F(y))<\varepsilon$ does not imply that $d(x,y)<\dfrac{\varepsilon}{C}$.  (The converse holds.)  For example, consider a constant map.

Comment: Thanks a lot. But how do we know that the measure of the $B^k$ in $B^n$ is zero?

Comment: @Navid: You can show that for every subset $E$ of $\mathbb R^k$, $E\times \{0_{n-k}\}$ has measure $0$ in $\mathbb R^n$.  Particularly for the case where $E$ has finite measure (like for $E=B^k$, note that $E\times\{0_{n-k}\}\subset E\times(-\varepsilon,\varepsilon)\times\cdots\times (-\varepsilon,\varepsilon)$ for all $\varepsilon>0$, so $m(E\times\{0_{n-k}\})\leq m(E)(2\varepsilon)^{n-k}$.  Since $\varepsilon$ was arbitrary and $m(E)<\infty$, this implies that $m(E\times\{0_{n-k}\})=0$.  (To generalize to $m(E)=+\infty$, note that $E$ is a countable union of finite measure sets.)

Comment: That makes sense, thank you. But I don't really get that last part where you generalize to $m(E) = \infty$. Perhaps there is some theorem that is implied. Sorry but we just learned the definition measure zero last week.

Comment: @Navid: Given any $E$, note that $E= \cup_i E\cap [-i,i]^k$.  Each $E\cap[-i,i]^k$ has finite measure, so $m((E\cap [-i,i]^k)\times\{0_{n-k}\})=0$, and therefore $m(E\times\{0_{n-k}\})\leq\sum_i m((E\cap[-i,i]^k)\times\{0_{n-i}\})=\sum_i 0=0$.  (Of course this generalization is tangential because $m(B^k)<\infty$.)  A countable union of sets of measure $0$ has measure $0$.

Comment: Alright, thanks for all the help.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can use the fact that a Lipschitz map is a.e. differentiable, say outside of a set $S$ with $m(S)=0$ , and then apply Sard's theorem (wherever differentiability holds, i.e., in $B^k-S$ ), so that every point in $\mathbb R^k \cap B^k$ is a critical point, so that $f(B^k -S)$ has measure zero in $B^n$. So all we need to deal with is the image of S under F.

Or, more easily,for this last, use that a Lipschitz function is absolutely continuous, so that , since S has measure zero, and a.continuity takes measure zero to measure zero, we have $m(f(S))=0$ , and you're done.